# chrome.tabs.sendMessage not working while sendResponse works

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

### Here is the manifest of the chrome extension :

```
{
  "name": "myconnector",
  "short_name": "myconnector",
  "version": "1.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "myapp",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js"],
    "persistent": true
    },
    "externally_connectable": {
      "ids": ["*"],
      "matches": ["*://*.myurl.fr/*"]
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [ "emulation.js", "content_scripts.js" ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon-16.png",
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

### Background page of the chrome extension :

```
//------ Message received from external web site

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if(request.areYouThere) {
        onNativeMessage(true);
    }

    if(!port) {
        port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
        //port.onMessage.addListener( onNativeMessage );
    }

    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {sendResponse(msg);});

     port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
        console.log("Disconnected from native App");
        port = null;
    });

    if (request.data) {
      var data = request.data;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
      port.postMessage(data);
    }

    return true;

  });

// ----- Message received from Native Host App

function onNativeMessage( message ) {
    console.log( 'received message from native app: ' + JSON.stringify( message ) );
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, message, function(response){});
    });
}
```

### And here is the code of the web site calling the extension :

```
$("#my-action").click(function(){

            console.log("calling method MyAction");

            chrome.runtime.sendMessage( "<extension id>",  
                                {data: 
                                    {action:"MyAction"}
                                    }, 
                                function(response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
        });
```

When I do this :

```
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {sendResponse(msg);});
```

The response is correctly sent but I get a chrome.native.lastError.message :

> Cannot send a response more than once per chrome.runtime.onMessage
>   listener per document (message was sent by extension for URL
>   undefined).

But when I do this :

```
port.onMessage.addListener( onNativeMessage );
```

This method calling onNativeMessage sents a message back to the web site (allegedly ?) using the method chrome.tabs.sendMessage. But the web site never gets the response.

Furthermore, my extension needs to instantiate a port so it can use long-lived connection with my native host app.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: This is an **extension**, not an **app**. Modifying the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I do this :
>
> ```
> port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {sendResponse(msg);});
> ```
>
> The response is correctly sent but I get a `chrome.runtime.lastError.message` :
>
> > Cannot send a response more than once per `chrome.runtime.onMessage` listener per document (message was sent by extension for URL undefined).

That's because you're adding a listener EVERY time you get an external message. So after getting the second message, `sendResponse()` tries to run twice (the new one and the old one again).

---

> But when I do this :
>
> ```
> port.onMessage.addListener( onNativeMessage );
> ```
>
> This method calling `onNativeMessage` sends a message back to the web site (allegedly ?) using the method `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. But the web site never gets the response.

You can't do that; `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` sends a message to the [content script context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), not the webpage.

---

You should modify your code to only add the listeners once, or at least ensuring that there is one listener at a time.

The trick, of course, is that `sendResponse` reference changes every time. I guess you can do it with a self-deregistering listener:

```
if(!port) {
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);

    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
      console.log("Disconnected from native App");
      port = null;
    });
}

var callback = function(msg) {
  sendResponse(msg);
  port.onMessage.removeListener(callback); // The power of closures!
};

port.onMessage.addListener(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and exhaustive answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: Dear @Xan, I have an extension (as my background) which communicate with an external page (as my content script). How is possible to terminate listening in the content script side? I am using port.onMessage.removeListener(this); , however it is not worked!

Comment: @Aqjn Ask a new question with more details, do not try to ask follow-up questions in comments.